# How to offset Map center

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mapkit

I have an app with a preview of a map who animates full screen after taping on it:

[image]

Because of the translucent bar at the bottom of the mapView, I managed to offset the center of the map by calling `mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapView.visibleMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0), animated: false)`
after the map finished:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 700
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Now I want to expand the `mapView` to fill the entire Screen.
The good thing is the maps zoom and position stays as they are and just the frame expands, exactly as intended (the userPosition is still centered, but not visible because its right behind the top of the translucent panel, *just compare the map*):

[image]

The bad thing is, I want the maps center to be between the blue box and the translucent panel. The problem is, when I try to offset the map to display the users position at center of the new visible area of the map.
I need to use the function `setVisibleMapRect` again (as far as I understand) to set a new edgePadding. But everything I tested ends with the map zooming in or out and when I jump between expanded and collapsed state I more and more zooming out.

So I search a way to just offset the map a bit to show user position correctly, something like `mapView.setEdgePadding(UIEdgeInsets(...), animated: true)`
or  I need a way to calculate the correct `MKMapRect` based on the current zoomlevel and the new frame, so I can use the `setVisibleMapRect` function without changing the maps zoom level.

The result I want:

[image]

Comment: A solution not but a workaround, I post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment of the question, I did not find a solution but a workaround.

This workaround has the desired result but did not animate simultaneously with the rest, instead it starts after view animation finished:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: recentMapController.addressContainer.frame.maxY, // blue upper box
                                  left: 0,
                                  bottom: recentMapController.panelView.frame.height, // blurred panel
                                  right: 0)
recentMapController.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(recentMapController.mapView.visibleMapRect, edgePadding: insets, animated: true)
```

I put this in my completion handler of the `UIViewPropertyAnimator` I used to animate from collapsed to expand view:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, timingParameters: springParameters)

animator.addCompletion { _ in
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: recentMapController.addressContainer.frame.maxY,
                                      left: 0,
                                      bottom: recentMapController.panelView.frame.height,
                                      right: 0)
    recentMapController.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(recentMapController.mapView.visibleMapRect, edgePadding: insets, animated: true)
}
```

Hope this helps everyone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: // Size of bottom modal,
        right: 0
    )
}
```

or

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    mapView.layoutMargins.bottom = // Size of bottom modal
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want the user a little more dynamically centered, consider one of these:

```
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: animated)

mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: animated)
```

This can change the zoom level.

If you want to set the center the users position only once, try:

```
var region  = mapView.region
region.center = userLocation
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

This should not change the zoom level.

Comment: The problem is not to show user location at the center of the map. I need to tell the map that just parts of its view are visible in which the center should be defined.

Comment: Did you try the part after "If you want to set the center the users position only once, try"?

Comment: Yes, I already had this. I updated my question for more information.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you give your map less pixels and mapView makes the map *content* smaller so you see the same area as before?